# Cannot use click action in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried add click function on

item, but seems that does not work correctly.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#vibrateBtn").click(function() {
 window.alert('test');
 });
 });
```

I tried also disable Ajax loading, with>

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
 ajaxEnabled:false;
});
```

But with same result.

Where can be problem please?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could we see you HTML markup as well?

Answer (score 2):

in jquery mobile document.ready() doesn't work and use .live to bind the click event instead of using the short hard .click().
There are other event like pagebeforecreate, pagecreate. check the [jquery demo](http://jquerymobile.com/test/) for the list of event.

```
$(document).live('pageshow',function(){

   $("#vibrateBtn").live('click',function() {
        window.alert('test');
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

    $(function() {
     $('#theButton').on('tap click',function(event, ui) {
        alert('The Button has been clicked');
     });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <input type="button" id="theButton" name="theButton" value="The Button">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```